# Google Visualization chart - change localization

Tags: google-visualization, iccube-reporting

Is there a way to set the locale on the google visualization widgets in icCube

Looking at google documentation this can be done only when loading the library and not at widget level.

```
 google.charts.load('current', {packages:['corechart'],'language': 'de'});
```

Answer (score 2):

1) You could configure widget number/date formats in the widget options:
Vertical Axes(or Horizontal Axis) -> Vertical Axis New(0) -> Format

2) Other option is to change the locale for the whole loaded library. To do that you can disable automatic loading in the config JS(admin menu):

```
  function ic3config(options) {
    options.libs.GoogleViz = false;
  }
```

and after that load library manually with different arguments

```
function ic3bootstrapLocal(options) {    
    $script("https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js", function () {
      google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'geochart', 'table', 'sankey', 'calendar'], 'language': 'de'});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
          ic3globals.libs.GoogleViz = true;
          options.callback && options.callback();
        });
    })  
}
```